# Grails unique constraint on Domain list

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

If I have a domain Person and a Domain Hobby, and Person hasMany Hobby, how can I make sure the same Hobby isn't added more than once to the Person collection.

i.e. something like

`

```
   class Hobby {
      String name
      static belongsTo = [person: Person] 
   }
   class Person
      String name

      static hasMany =[hobby: Hobby]

      static constraints= {
        hobby.name unique: true           //like this
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the prefect use case for a custom `validator`. I suggest reading the [documentation](http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Constraints/validator.html) so you get a feeling for what is possible with one, but you could use something like this:

```
class Hobby {
   String name
   static belongsTo = [person: Person]
}
class Person
   String name

   static hasMany = [hobby: Hobby]

   static constraints = {
      hobby validator: { val, obj ->
         if (obj.hobby.find{ (it.name.equals(val.name) && it.id != val.id) } ) return ['unique']
      }
   }
}
```

The above is just something off the top of my head, there may be typos or logic errors, but it's an example of how you can implement your own check using a custom `validator`.

**UPDATE**
Gregg's answer about making the `Hobby` unique per `Person` is actually a much simpler and cleaner way to address this. As he points out there is actually no need for a custom validator since the relationship exists between `Person` and `Hobby`.

Comment: I suppose the 'val' argument in validator closure here will be the whole list of hobbies , hence this solution will not work. We have to iterate over 'val' and chechk if there are duplicates

Answer (score 6):

I know this has been answered but the easiest way is really to do this:

```
class Hobby {
  String name
  static belongsTo = [person: Person] 

  static constraints = {
    name unique: 'person'
  }
}
```

This will ensure that a `hobby` has a unique name per it's parent, `person`. No need for a custom validator.

Comment: Excellent point Gregg! I suppose I should finish my morning coffee before answering questions.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore I read your answer and the question many times before adding mine. I thought surely Joshua knows what he's doing here. :) Thought I had to be missing something.

Comment: Simplest is always best solution.

Answer (score -1):

The documentation (http://docs.grails.org/2.5.5/guide/GORM.html#sets,ListsAndMaps) says that a collection defined with `hasMany` is a `java.util.Set`. And a `Set` cannot contain duplicates.

So I think you don't have to define a constraint and you have your requested behavior by default.

Comment: I don't think that would work.  What's unique in the set is the id.  What I'm trying to prevent is duplicating the "name" field.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think that works either.  Possible that two separate people have a hobby called "Fishing"